# Can't use the address that I just created using cardano-addresses

Tags: wallet

I just used cardano-addresses software to create a wallet and two addresses that can receive tADA. But I can't access any information of these address using Cardano Explorer. Or check if the tADA's where received.

addr_test1vzlz473fksrprx8g6z0d72lwj46lsrjutx69uvhq0s8yjvg6hnfrr

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your address and transactions on the "Preview" testnet *(not to be confused with the "Pre-Production" testnet)*:

https://preview.cexplorer.io/address/addr_test1vzlz473fksrprx8g6z0d72lwj46lsrjutx69uvhq0s8yjvg6hnfrr

https://preview.cexplorer.io/tx/a11dd3e1dee2a626999a3fdced8c7c49dbb3f3b89343a2e17c40185d503bb4a6

Some info on the environments:

https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html#preview-testnet

Comment: Can I put these tADA's on pre-pod?
Or I don't need that to receive the values on my address?

Comment: You can’t move them over, but you can get new tAda through the faucet here, just select the PreProd environment: https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-testnet/tools/faucet

Answer (score 0):

The explorer gets these address (so they can be displayed) from the block chain. If these addresses have not received any funds, the explorer cannot know about them.